# How to read Folder Tag value inside S3 Bucket in Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have creaated one folder inside my S3 Bucket and given some tag value to that folder. I am not able to access tag value through Java AWS SDK code tried following documentation
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/tagging-manage-javasdk.html
but no luck.
Can anyone please help me out.

i tried like

```
 GetObjectTaggingRequest getTaggingRequest = new 
 GetObjectTaggingRequest(BUCKET_NAME,"folder1/folder2/");
 GetObjectTaggingResult  getTagsResult =   s3client.getObjectTagging(getTaggingRequest);
```

Comment: What does "not able to access" mean?  An error? An empty result?  The object key for a folder named `bar` that is inside a folder named `foo` is `foo/bar/` -- note the trailing slash on the end.  That is required if you are looking at a "folder" (which is another discussion entirely, but for now we'll focus on the core issue).  Please show your code.

Comment: i have folder folder1/folder2/ inside bucket ,i want to access Tag field of folder2.

Comment: Michael - sqlbot : i have update question can you please look on it? thanks

Comment: So, you appear to be making the correct request.  What happens next?  Error?  No data?  Also, how did you originally add the tags to the folder?

Comment: yes i am getting zero size in tag list. And i have added tag manualy in s3 console while clicking properties of folder.

Comment: @ Michael - sqlbot can u reply?